# How to deploy solr4 in jboss6

Tags: solr, jboss6.x

What is the best way to deploy solr 4.x in a running jboss 6.x application server instance?

Answer (score 1):

Well, JBoss features an embedded Tomcat, so I'd start by reading the docs about [Solr and Tomcat](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat). There's also some specific [docs for JBoss](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrJBoss), and of course there's the [wiki page for general installation instructions](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrInstall).